# tcl/tk - how to make frameless window that open in the of cursor position invoked by button right of the mouse

Tags: linux, window, tcl, frame, tk-toolkit

The idea is how to open popup next to the event button - it's to get Onclick Mouse Cursor Position

It would be like this, when clicking anywhere on the desktop, you should call the program in `Tcl/Tk` at the mouse pointer location. This `Tcl/Tk`t program should be without embroidery, window frame.

I know I did it ha good temp ago, in the year 2017, at the time I used `Tcl/Tk 8.4` to display only the tk window without frame.

Now I don't remember how I did it and I need someone's help to clear my mind.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current absolute position of the mouse pointer, use `winfo pointerxy $w` (the `$w` is used to work out which “display” you're talking about in an X11 sense, and is pretty irrelevant these days; you can actually use any window there, but it is a required argument anyway).

To move a (toplevel) window to the pointer, you set its geometry. Combining the two, you get this:

```
proc movewintoptr w {
    lassign [winfo pointerxy $w] x y
    wm geometry $w +$x+$y
}
```

You might want to consider offsetting the window a bit. (Exactly how best to do that depends on what you are showing in the window; the code gets very application specific.)

---

To make a toplevel window that has no decorations, do:

```
toplevel $w
wm overrideredirect $w 1
```

Be aware that undecorated windows can't be easily manipulated by the user by default. You have to implement all that part yourself (if it is relevant).

And yes, the `wm overrideredirect` call should be very soon after the toplevel is created; windows can't usually be swapped between display modes once they're displaying on the screen (and that depends on how window managers work, etc).